# Stackoverflow-error when executing a POST with Angular HttpClient instead of VanillaJS fetch()

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

Consider a Java Spring Boot backend with two entities: Client and ClientDetails:

Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Client{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
  private String firstName;
  @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
  private String lastName;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "client-details")
  private ClientDetails clientDetails;
}
```

Client-Details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_details")
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ClientDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "e_mail")
  private String eMail;
  @Column(name = "phone")
  private String phone;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
  @JsonManagedReference(value = "client-details")
  private Client client;
}
```

In my frontend, I want to execute a POST request. For this purpose, I am reading in a form using the FormData API. The result is a JSON looking like this:

```
{eMail: "firstName.lastName@example.com", phone: "1234-5678910", client: {firstName: "myFirstName", lastName: "myLastName"}}
```

In my backend, I have added a controller for POST requests.

I used to send the POST request using Vanilla JS and the fetch method. Everything used to work fine back then. Now, I have switched to Angular. I am using the HTTPClient to send the POST request now:

I have created a CRUD-service with the following method:

```
  addClient(clientDetails: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.URL, JSON.stringify(clientDetails), this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Upon clicking a button, I subscribe to this method and the POST request is executed:

```
  onButtonClick() {
    this.clientDetailsCrudService.addClient(this.readFormData()).subscribe((returnValue) => console.log(returnValue));
  }
```

The `addClient()` method is passed the correct JSON, I have verified this. However, it seems that my backend is having troubles with the JsonBackReference and JsonManagedReference variables, as I am running into a stackoverflow error, which seems to be related to some toString method:

StackoverflowError
at com.company.example.entity.ClientDetails.toString
at com.company.example.entity.Client.toString

So my question really is: Is there a difference between the way the fetch() method and the HttpClient.post() method are executing a POST request? Because the exact same backend used to work allright with fetch(). Does anyone have a suggestion as on how to solve this problem?

===========================================================

Update:

I managed to solve this issue with the first answer given to [this](https://at%20com.company.example.entity.Client.toString) question. It says: Remove the `@Data` annotation and replace it with `@Getter` and `@Setter`.

While I am so grateful for this answer, I don't understand it: I am not actively calling the `toString()` method. Now, if it is called, is this related to Angular's HttpClient? Because I didn't have this problem with fetch().

Comment: What happens when you don’t stringify your payload?

Comment: Hi MikeOne, I have tried that, the result is the same. ... what is so disturbing about this error message is also that I was expecting to see maybe sth like `infinite recursion`, but instead it just says `StackoverflowError` and then in the stack trace it says alternating `at ClientDetails.toString` and `at Client.toString`

Comment: As @MikeOne pointed, in your working case you are logging something or stringify the entity ? Because the error seems related to the json annotations.

Comment: I just realized: The error occurs even before the POST-controller in my backend is called. I have added a `System.out` inside the controller method and it is never called. So, apparently there is sth wrong with deserializing the `@RequestBody`. Well, actually I don't know, but the controller method body is not executed.

Comment: allright, I have updated my question. It seems the error is because of Lombok.

Comment: @Luk but stackoverflow error means exactly infinite recursion. Java has max call stack (default to 200) and if recursion runs more iterations than that it throws stack overflow error.